# How can I add new page in a sub folder using Ionic Cli

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, ionic-cli

I want to add a new page to an existing project under a specific folder.
e.g: I want to add `student-entry-form` under `pages/forms`

```
ionic g page forms/student-entry-form
```

I used the above command but it created `forms-student-entry-form` under pages.

Is there any way I can achieve `pages/forms/student-entry-form` using Ionic Cli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till now i havent received any answer here and nor any luck after reading many articles.
So, for now i have created a page using

```
ionic g page student-entry-form
```

and then moved (copy paste or drag'N'drop ) the folder under sub-folder. i.e pages/forms.
This is just a workaround. Please drop an answer whenever you have one.
Thanks.

Edit:
**Now using Ionic4 we have a solution**

```
ionic g page pages/student-entry-form
```

Using the above command we can, add a page **student-entry-form** under **pages** folder